# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken Android Client - Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the following entity in appengine

```
@Api(
        name = "profileendpoints", 
        version = "v1", 
        scopes = {EMAIL_SCOPE}, 
        clientIds = {ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID, WEB_CLIENT_ID},
        audiences = {WEB_CLIENT_ID}
        )
public class ProfileEndPoints {
    ...
}
```

In android project, in onCreate method of MainActivity, I have the ff:

```
    settings = getSharedPreferences("profile", 0);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
       "server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID);
```

But I got the following error:

```
I/dalvikvm(477): Could not find method  
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken, referenced from method 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken
```

I have the following jar files in `libs` folder of my android project.

```
google-api-client-1.16.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.16.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-1.16.0-rc.jar
gson-2.1.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method is part of Google Play Services. Make sure Google Play Services is [installed](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), added as a dependency to your project, and available on the device (or emulator) you're running the app on.